# xcode apigee logInUserWithFacebook extra parameter?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, apigee

I'm using Apigee for my iphone/ipad app.
Like many apps today, mine requires a login via Facebook and Apigee has a function specifically for this in the iOs framework, here's how it's called:

```
[ApigeeDataClient logInUserWithFacebook:[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken];
```

As far as my code goes, everything works well up until the above line. I'm receiving the following error.

> Response: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"missing access token"}

However check out how the function is making the call (from the logs):

> Synch outgoing call: 'https://api.usergrid.com/sgfishing/deepseafishing/auth/facebook?ql=fb_access_token=CAADrhKxrQp4BANfZCMuZBdOwUL9nc0H4VzZC1EXVLjABRbcrucTlUgwlKczFinl51GIWyBM5nlZBX1RF84azFAEOfChqN7vgSmvqgwybV8iPU2xjncZB9T5YTdY0pesJkHsSlvOafMhQ6MfIa6qdZCbTYBZCFB2oIPgEnro4runJKcqCy68wZCFQwyIzACVThAC3IEjZADs36hToQxhYZBzAWVhbKlcqJQsroZD'

I would like to bring your attention to this `...facebook?<b>ql=</b>fb_access_token=CAADrh....`

I'm not sure why `ql=` is there, I've checked the definition of `logInUserWithFacebook` and `ql=` is nowhere to be found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in our iOS SDK. It has been fixed in version 2.0.9 of our SDK (released yesterday).

Answer (score 0):

?ql= is typically used for [query language statements](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/querying-your-data) see if there is any such code around in your program

This just a tip...may help